# How to debug less css variables

Tags: css, less

As the title stated, how would I debug less css variables. For an example.

```
//style.less
@height: `document.body.clientHeight`;
```

Comment: Debug how? Check the final CSS?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Debug in this case, but the first issue I see is your variable is declared wrong. It is declared like this: @title: 'hello world';

Comment: Sorry for the bad example, basically would like to check the javascript value generated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on @GeekyMonkey's answer, I wrote this little snipped you can put somewhere in your less file:

```
.debug(@var) {
  &:after {
    content: "@{var}";
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  }
}
```

Then just use `.debug(@someVar)` and get its value printed to the screen. :-)

Comment: Brilliant!  Gotta love the reusable mixins.

Comment: This is useful but i wish there was something like console.log, it's really challanging sometimes when you have unknown/absurd compiler errors.

Comment: But where do we use that? on the html? on the console? Sorry but I think this answer is incomplete

Answer (score 6):

You can output values as text by using them in a :before or :after psuedo-element's content.

```
.Panel:after
{
    content: "@{PanelPadding}";
}
```